# TFS GIT Pull Request Rule: Add reviewer from 2nd group when someone from 1st group approved PR

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

I wanted to apply the rule in PR merge policy on tfs git as we have 2 different user groups of lets say A and B. When any user Approved PR from group A,only then group B can be add as Reviewer else not.This transition data is critical for analyze purpose and for estimates between the two groups.

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to ask. please specify what are you trying to achieve, what methods have you tried if any and what results you got.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question, we have 2 user groups lets say UIUXs and Devs, once UIUXs people done with the design, they will approve the PR and add Devs as Reviewers, sometimes UIUXs people add Devs as from the beginning which i need to stop. So i need to embed a tweaking in the PR policy so that when UIUXs approve the PR only then Devs will be added as reviewer. Currently i dont find this in policy rules, suggest some alternatives

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the comment, what you are looking for is not available in web portal at present. We do not have this kind of build-in policy rules.

> When any user Approved PR from group A, **only then group B can be add
>   as Reviewer else not.**

It is not able to do this so far. We could not add some conditions to judge who could be added as a PR reviewer or not.

Comment: @ASD Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have missed the most important part `When any user Approved PR from group A, **only then group B can be add as Reviewer else not.**` It is not able to do this so far. We could not add some conditions to judge who could be added as a PR reviewer or not. Have updated my reply. Sorry for any inconvenience.